# how to add payments directly between client/provider in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, stripe-payments

how to add payments directly between client/provider (and maybe I will take commission) in android studio?

Can I use stripe or any other thing to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you can use stripe.
Here you have the documentation, I can't write the full process here https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment